# Open up another application's database?

Tags: android, database

Let's say I make an app on Android, is there a way to access another app's database (in data/data/(other.app.package)/databases) with that app and read contents?

I have a rooted device.

Comment: Ever heard of a `ContentProvider`?

Comment: @XaverKapeller Yes, but it was my understanding that applications have their 'own space' and you cannot access the /data/ folders of other applications without having their signature. I need to access a database from another developer's app. Is that possible with ContentProvider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other app should allow you to do that by implementing `ContentProvider`. 
Hitting another apps database directly is not the best idea.

Each application is executed with different UID, so if you will not have rooted phone it will be impossible to achieve.

Comment: The app will only be used by me, so I don't really have to worry about other people's devices. I don't understand why I'm getting downvoted either. I couldn't find any decisive information on the subject and wanted to know for certain before I started a whole project. But thanks :)